# What is the difference between model.fit() an model.evaluate() in Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, model, keras, evaluate

I am using Keras with TensorFlow backend to train CNN models.

What is the between `model.fit()` and `model.evaluate()`? Which one should I ideally use? (I am using `model.fit()` as of now).

I know the utility of `model.fit()` and `model.predict()`. But I am unable to understand the utility of `model.evaluate()`. Keras documentation just says:

> It is used to evaluate the model.

I feel this is a very vague definition.

Comment: Since originally asked, a lot has happened, including the docs significantly improving; so I'll include a link here to the Keras API for Tensorflow 2.x Python API for "Model":  `compile` (Configures the model for training); `fit` (Trains the model for a fixed number of epochs); `evaluate` (Returns the loss value & metrics values for the model in test mode);  `predict` (Generates output predictions for the input samples) https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model

Answer (score 66, accepted):

`fit()` is for training the model with the given inputs (and corresponding training labels).

`evaluate()` is for evaluating the already trained model using the validation (or test) data and the corresponding labels. Returns the loss value and metrics values for the model.

`predict()` is for the actual prediction. It generates output predictions for the input samples.

Let us consider a simple regression example:

```
# input and output
x = np.random.uniform(0.0, 1.0, (200))
y = 0.3 + 0.6*x + np.random.normal(0.0, 0.05, len(y))
```

[image]

Now lets apply a regression model in keras:

```
# A simple regression model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1, input_shape=(1,)))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='rmsprop')

# The fit() method - trains the model
model.fit(x, y, nb_epoch=1000, batch_size=100)

Epoch 1000/1000
200/200 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.0023

# The evaluate() method - gets the loss statistics
model.evaluate(x, y, batch_size=200)     
# returns: loss: 0.0022612824104726315

# The predict() method - predict the outputs for the given inputs
model.predict(np.expand_dims(x[:3],1)) 
# returns: [ 0.65680361],[ 0.70067143],[ 0.70482892]
```

Comment: even model.fit() returns the loss and acc right? I am bit fuzzy with model.fit() and model.evaluate()

Comment: fit() is for training a model. It produces metrics for the training set, where as evaluate() is for a testing the trained model on the test set.

Comment: What does `evaluate()` return if we don't pass any `x` and `y` parameters? As far as I am aware their default values are `None` which means they are not necessary.

Comment: The fit() method also allows passing in the validation dataset with the training dataset. So if you train the model passing in both in the fit() method, is it expected that the accuracy and loss values will be same when you run the evaluate() method on the validation dataset after the training is done? I'm just curious

Comment: @vijayachandran-mariappan I have gotten the `recall`, `accuracy`, `auc`, and `precision` from the keras compile block. It's really handy. How do we access each metric separately so we can use them? It seems they are not accessible via dot syntax or subscripting.

Answer (score 12):

In Deep learning you first want to train your model. You take your data and split it into two sets: the training set, and the test set. It seems pretty common that 80% of your data goes into your training set and 20% goes into your test set.

Your training set gets passed into your call to `fit()` and your test set gets passed into your call to `evaluate()`. During the fit operation a number of rows of your training data are fed into your neural net (based on your batch size). After every batch is sent the fit algorithm does back propagation to adjust the weights in your neural net.

After this is done your neural net is trained. The problem is sometimes your neural net gets overfit which is a condition where it performs well for the training set but poorly for other data. To guard against this situation you run the `evaluate()` function to send new data (your test set) through your neural net to see how it performs with data it has never seen. There is no training occurring, this is purely a test. If all goes well then the score from training is similar to the score from testing.

Comment: Imagine that I have done fit + evaluate + predict with data set #1, and now I want to predict with data set #2 without doing any fit, is it possible? Do I still need to evaluate again too?.

Comment: There are two ways of training - supervised and unsupervised. Supervised data is where you know the answers so you fit and evaluate with data that you know the answer to and then you predict data that you don't have the answer to.

If you know the answers to data set #2 then you don't need to predict it. You can add it to data set #1 and refit and reevaluate to provide better prediction.

I you don't know the answers then you would send data set #2 through the predict function and then act off of the predictions.

Answer (score 4):

**fit()**: Trains the model for a given number of epochs (this is for training time, with the training dataset).

**predict()**: Generates output predictions for the input samples (this is for somewhere between training and testing time).

**evaluate()**: Returns the loss value & metrics values for the model in test mode (this is for testing time, with the testing dataset).

Answer (score 2):

While all the above answers explain what these functions : fit(), evaluate() or predict() do however more important point to keep in mind in my opinion is what data you should use for fit() and evaluate().

The most clear guideline that I came across in [Machine Learning Mastery](https://machinelearningmastery.com/difference-test-validation-datasets/) and particular quote in there:

**Training set**: A set of examples used for learning, that is to fit the parameters of the classifier.

**Validation set**: A set of examples used to tune the parameters of a classifier, for example to choose the number of hidden units in a neural network.

**Test set**: A set of examples used only to assess the performance of a fully-specified classifier.

: *By Brian Ripley, page 354, Pattern Recognition and Neural Networks, 1996*

You should not use the same data that you used to train(tune) the model (validation data) for evaluating the performance (generalization) of your fully trained model (evaluate).

**The test data used for evaluate() should be unseen/not used for training(fit()) in order to be any reliable indicator of model evaluation (for generlization).**

For Predict() you can use just one or few example(s) that you choose (from anywhere) to get quick check or answer from your model. I don't believe it can be used as sole parameter for generalization.

Comment: Is there any reason to use `evaluate()`? Since in `fit()` you can already pass the validation dataset. And in `predict()` we would use the test dataset?

Answer (score 2):

One thing which was not mentioned here, I believe needs to be specified. model.evaluate() returns a list which contains a loss figure and an accuracy figure. What has not been said in the answers above, is that the "loss" figure is the sum of ALL the losses calculated for each item in the x_test array. x_test would contain your test data and y_test would contain your labels. It should be clear that the loss figure is the sum of **ALL** the losses, not just one loss from one item in the x_test array.

Comment: Extremely helpful!

Comment: the loss figure is the average loss over the testing dataset (the sum of all the losses divided by the number of items in the testing dataset).

Answer (score 0):

I would say the mean of losses incurred from all iterations, not the sum. But sure, that's the most important information here, otherwise the modeler would be slightly confused.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As [per the documentation](https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/#:%7E:text=%5Bsource%5D-,evaluate%20method,-Model.evaluate), `model.evaluate()` returns the test loss (lower is better) and "metrics".

Metrics over here refers to all metrics which were included when the model was compiled.

To get that info for your particular model, you can `print(model.metric_names)`.

(These metrics are not *necessarily* going to be included in every model though.)

[Here's a list of metrics you can include when compiling the model](https://keras.io/api/metrics/).

Fit is the function you use after compilation in order to train the model.

Evaluate is only used once you are done training.