# How does model.evaluate() work in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, time-series, lstm

I'm training a model with a 4 day look back and 4 days future forecast. The last 4 days will be acting as a feature for the next days.

In that case if i have x_test as `[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]` and `y_test[[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4],[0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8]]`

if we do a `model.predict(x_test[0])`, the result `y(hat)` we need to comapare with `y[1].`

So how is `model.evaluate()` doing this comparison? if we comapre `y(hat)[0]` with `y[0]`, it is wrong right?

Comment: take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44843581/what-is-the-difference-between-model-fit-an-model-evaluate-in-keras)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned, if we give values for consecutive days then we can use the second set of 4 values to evaluate model predictions of the first set of 4. [ it is called the rolling window validation method]
But, Since your dataset is in the form of input - [first 4 values] / label - [next 4 values], here we do not need to evaluate result of `x_test[0]` with `y[1]` because the actual y value for `x_test[0]` is in the `y[0]`.

Comment: Sorry. I think i gave the wrong example here. I was referring to rolling window validation only. x_test as [[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5]] and y_test[[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4],[,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5]] . In this case how model.evaluate of keras works?

Comment: isn't it suppose to be the same? because we manually transform the dataset into consecutive sets of 4 and use those to predict and validate with related labels. this is possible and correct if only you train the model using the same like this.

Comment: oh..got it..while constructing x_test, y_test same transforming function which i used to create train set, will take care of this..understood